# Notify custom ListAdapter about changes on a specific object

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, fragment, listview-adapter

I have custom ListAdapter that extends ArrayAdapter :

```
private class MyPrivateClassListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<someObject> {

            private ArrayList<someObject> items;

            public MyPrivateClassListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<someObject> items) {
                    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                    this.items = items;                             
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = convertView;


                    if (v == null)
                    {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        //cashedHolder=new CashedValuesForListView(convertView);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.some_xml, null);

                    }


                    someObject o = items.get(position);      

                    if (o != null) {    

                                TextView myTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myTextboxId);


                                myText.setText("some text");

                    }
                    return v;
            }
        }
```

This ArrayAdapter is inside my main activity so I'm calling it on my main activity on click:

```
  this.m_adapter = new MyPrivateClassListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.rows_to_fill, someObject);
         myList.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

So far so good, but problem is that from this main activity I'm calling another Fragment that is going to change values (on some click fired) inside myListview (for instance it 'll set another text on a specific row.).

I'm able to change value inside listview for short notice (after scrolling list it goes back to old state afcorse):

```
int visiblePosition = myList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mylist.getChildAt(itemIndex - visiblePosition);

 TextView mytextView = (TextView )v.findViewById(R.id.myTextboxId);         
 mytextView.setTxt("I ' va changed");
```

, what is a proper way doing this ( telling to custom adapter that data is changed (caused by instanced fragment)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to make change in the arraylist and notify the listview with a call to notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: I found the way, something like  this (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)
in order to communicate between fragments ofcourse